# Embed yammer group feed into jade (node.js view engine)

Tags: node.js, pug, yammer, express-4

I am trying to embed the yammer group feed into my node.js website (Express4) jade view. Here's what I am doing in the jade view :

```
extends layout

block content
  h2 #{title}
  h3 #{message}
  p Use this area to provide additional information.

  script(src="https://assets.yammer.com/platform/yam.js")

  div(id="embedded-feed")

  script
      yam.connect.embedFeed(container='embedded-feed', network='mycompany.com', feedType='group', feedId='999999')
```

However, when I load the page I get the following pop-up :

[image]

Has anyone embedded yammer or other feeds into jade ?

Comment: Works fine with ejs though.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than including the script `https://assets.yammer.com/platform/yam.js` you should be including `https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js` as per the documentation at https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/embed.